# Can't edit tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I recently created a temporary tag, as part of a clean-up project (june-2011-faq-revamp).

I went to edit the tag wiki to explain the purpose of the tag, by visiting this page:

https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/june-2011-faq-revamp/info

As well as explaining that there is "There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!" it provides a "Create Tag Wiki" button.

Clicking on the button redirects me to same page, with no form. I expected it to lead me to a page/form for me to edit the wiki-text.

Browser: Google Chrome 12.0.742.91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Jeff in another meta question:](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2362/unable-to-propose-tag-wiki)

> We're not currently allowing tag wikis
>   to be edited on metas, as we plan to
>   push out the shared meta tag wikis
>   from meta.so.
>
> This may change in the future.

It is not intended that the tag wikis are customized for each meta, so this is not a bug.